# Determining the Linq to SQL Connection User Account

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using **Linq to SQL** & **.NET 4.0** to make a connection to a local **SQL 2008 Express Server**. I am getting the following error.

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed. The login
>    is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

In order to debug this, I would like to know if I can determine the user account my code uses to make a connection to the **SQL Express Server**.

**My code:** 
This is the first lines of code to execute using a **Console Application**.

```
AMSCMDataContext db = new AMSCMDataContext();
var t = db.CMHomePageStatusLogs.ToList(); //Causes above Exception
Logger.Log(LogType.TRACE | LogType.CONSOLE, "Count: {0}", t.Count);
```

My **Connection String** in **App Config**:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AMS_CM_DL.Properties.Settings.AMSCMDBConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AMSCMDB;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**Background:**

I originally developed this code on **Windows 7**. I then moved the code to **Windows XP** - without recompiling it, but it now connects to the same DB which is again **local** to the **WinXP** machine. I am running this as a **Console Application** *(on the commandline)* and as **Admin** on both **Windows 7** and **Windows XP**. As an Admin, I can verify that I can successfully connect to the **local DB** using **SQL Server Management Studio** as well as **SQLCMD.exe**. The complete exception is:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed. The login
>    is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception
>   , Boolean breakConnection)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cm
>   dHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, Tds
>   ParserStateObject stateObj)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlis
>   tOK)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeo
>   ut, SqlConnection owningObject)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection ow
>   ningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnecti
>   on owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, St
>   ring newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdent
>   ity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String
>    newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOp
>   tions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection
>    owningConnection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConn
>   ection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owning
>   Object)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection o
>   wningObject)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection ownin
>   gObject)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection ow
>   ningConnection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection ou
>   terConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionU
>   ser user)
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe()
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode()
>      at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider
>   .Execute(Expression query)
>      at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.GetEnumerator()
>      at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.G
>   etEnumerator()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at Handler.Handler.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\UserName\docu
>   ments\visual studio 2010\Projects\AMS_CM_ETC\Handler\Handler.cs:line 64

**Update:**

I would like to add that my **Windows 7** machine is associated with corporate domain. The **Windows XP** Machine on the other hand is not under any domain. I don’t think this should affect though, should it? Though I compiled on a **Win 7** machine and I am running on **Win XP**, I don't see this corporate domain codified anywhere in the code.

**Update 2:**

I was able to a bit more debugging. First I created a simple **VS Solution** on the **Win XP** machine. I put a **DBML** *(LINQ to SQL)* file, and put the above code in the `Main` method of the `Program.cs` file. This worked.

Next, I would like to point out that while the above posted code is the first to execute in my original **Solution**, the **Solution** is a lot more complex. In fact the above code executes from something that would be my **Business Layer Project**, while the `AMSCMDataContext` is defined in the **DataLayer Project**. I then made the **DataLayer Project** a **Console Application**, and put the above mentioned code into the `Main` method of a class in the **DataLayer**. This works.

**So to summarize:**

I get the above `exception` if I call the code from the **Business Layer Project** of a larger Solution, but the same code would work if I ran it from the **DataLayer Project** of the same Solution *(where the DBML file is)*. Can someone throw some light on how to handle this **Trust** issue?

**Possible Solution:**

I’m sorry for writing so much, but for those who want a summary: The three lines of C# code posted above works in the **Data Layer**, but not from the **Business Layer** i.e. you get the above mentioned `Exception`. This is not a connection issue because the **Data Layer** can connect.

The solution is to first go into the **Data Layer** executable directory i.e. `/bin/Debug` or `/bin/Release` and find the **Config file** of the **Executable** i.e. it would be of the form `ExeName.exe.config`. This file has the **Connection String** information. Next, go into the **Business Layer** executable directory, and see if there a **Config** file for the **Executable**. If no, then simply copy the **Data Layer Config** file here, and **rename** it according to the format `BusinessLayerExeName.exe.config`. If there is already an existing **Config** file in the **Business Layer** executable directory, open it copy the **Connection String** information from the **Data Layer** into it. Now the **Business Layer** works too!

Comment: When you connect via SSMS, are you sure that you are selecting "Windows Authentication" from the drop down list? This bit `Integrated Security=True` of your connection string, says connect to database as the same windows account that is running the console app.

Comment: I am using **Windows Authentication** throughout. I have not set a password on the Server/DB. Using the same Console/Commandline, I can use SQLCMD to connect, so I don't know what the problem is?

Comment: Err, it's 2014.  Get a Win7 license and get rid of that XP install ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit murky but I have a few ideas for you to try out.

Look at the properties on your dbml file:
Perhaps you are not selecting the connection string that you think you are selecting.  Specifying a connection string in the app.config does not mean your application is using that string.  Right click properties on the dbml and look at which connection string is being used.

App.config vs web.config etc:
Are you sure that your app.config settings are not be overwritten by the project using the dll?  I think this isn't relevant to your situation but thought I'd mention.

Debug It:
Drop a debug point on the opening of the database connection.  Check out what connection you are trying to make.

Trace It:
Start a trace on your local (or other database if you have sufficient privileges) and then launch your application.  You should see the connection come in and can examine the connection request.

Domain vs Local Users:
If you are trying to connect to your local database in both scenarios, I don't think your credentials are your problem.  However, if you are trying to connect to a named database that is part of the domain, you probably aren't going to be able to do that (easily) with your local user on your win xp machine.

Difference In Database Names:
Is it possible that you installed the full version of SQL Server on your Win 7 machine (which likely has a default database instance name like MSSQLSERVER) but installed SQL Express on your Win XP machine (which likely has a default database instance name of SQLEXPRESS).  Or perhaps you have a named instance (MYAPPDB to make one up) on your Win7 machine but just have the default instance name on your local machine?

Project type:
This stack overflow question reports that changing from .NET Framework Client Profile to .NET Framework has helped in what sounds like a potentially similar situation.  [Referencing DBML project in Console App (.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511700/referencing-dbml-project-in-console-app-net)

I hope one of these ideas helps you.

Comment: Thank you **Keith Hoffman**, but I don't think these apply to me. First, I replicated this problem with a simpler Solution containing only two **Console Applications**. There is only one **connection string** in the project, and only one **app.config**. I can get the **Console Application** that contains the DBML file to connect, but I cannot get the other **Console Application** that uses the first as a reference to work. One think I failed to mention was that the **Win 7** was on a domain while the **Win XP** isn't. This may be a problem, but both connect to the local **SQL Express**

Comment: What's your project structure?  Is your dbml file in a separate dll in your original console application or in the console application project itself?  Have you tried breaking out your data model into a standalone project in the original console app solution (so it will be a separate dll) or into a standalone solution?

Comment: Thank you **Keith Hoffman**. For now I am only dealing with **Console Applications**. My **DBML** file is in a **Console Application**. Running the code from this Application I can connect. If I attempt the same code in another **Console Application** in the same **Solution** obviously referencing the first **Console Application**, I get the `Exception` mentioned in my original post.

Comment: Thank you **Keith Hoffman**. I tried changing the **.NET Framework Client Profile** to **.NET Framework** and it did not work. I think the only thing that works is manually copying the **Connection Strings** in the config file from the **Data Layer** exe directory to the **Business Layer**.

Comment: "Business Layer"?  Sounds like you have two layers: the application and the model (dbml).  Out of curiosity, did you try separating your dbml from the console application project?